# How can I add an new property to a list item in flutter / dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following `List`

```
[
{thumb: 28986/H6a6Xkm_thumb.jpeg, full: 28986/H6a6Xkm.jpeg}, 
{thumb: 28986/f-2_thumb.jpg, full: 28986/f-2.jpg}, 
{thumb: 28986/Ft_thumb.jpg, full: 28986/Ft.jpg}, 
{thumb: 28986/FED_thumb.jpg, full: FED.jpg}
]
```

I wanted to try to add a new property to each of these 4 items called `desc` which would be a description, lets say for now: `Apple`

Is there an easy way to iterate the list and insert the new property so the final result would be:

```
[
{thumb: 28986/H6a6Xkm_thumb.jpeg, full: 28986/H6a6Xkm.jpeg, desc: Apple}, 
{thumb: 28986/f-2_thumb.jpg, full: 28986/f-2.jpg, desc: Apple}, 
{thumb: 28986/Ft_thumb.jpg, full: 28986/Ft.jpg, desc: Apple}, 
{thumb: 28986/FED_thumb.jpg, full: FED.jpg, desc: Apple}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate over the list with `map` method and inside it return the new map with the spread operator like this:

```dart
final myList = [{"hello": "world"}];
final newList = myList.map((obj) => {...obj, "desc": "Apple"}).toList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Is your list a list of maps?

The easiest way to edit every value in a list is using the `.map` method:

```
myList = myList.map((value) => newValue).toList();
```

so for example say you have a list of numbers and want to add one to each of them

```
myList = myList.map((number) => number+1).toList();
```

you can also pass more calculations like so:

```
myList = myList.map((value) {
  // some calculations
  return newValue;
}).toList();
```

Here is how to solve your problem with that code assuming your list is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
myList = myList.map((value) => value..addAll({'desc': 'apple'})).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an for loop or the forEach list property to add an element to the lists:

```
void main() async {
  var list = [
    {'thumb': '28986/H6a6Xkm_thumb.jpeg', 'full': '28986/H6a6Xkm.jpeg'},
    {'thumb': '28986/f-2_thumb.jpg', 'full': '28986/f-2.jpg'},
    {'thumb': '28986/Ft_thumb.jpg', 'full': '28986/Ft.jpg'},
    {'thumb': '28986/FED_thumb.jpg', 'full': 'FED.jpg'}
  ];

   /// using for loop
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) list[i]['desc_for'] = 'Apple';
  print(list);
  
  /// Using forEach 
  list.forEach((item) {
    item['desc_forEach'] = 'Apple';
  });
  print(list);
}
```